# Is there available MVC based stylesheet framework.?

Tags: model-view-controller, frameworks, stylesheet

Did you know, the best MVC based stylesheet framework?. And, can please tell me the features of that framework(s)?.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that stylesheets are there to provide... styling... which is presentation only, I would say that they belong in the V component on the MVC.

And, as such, I don't really why / how you'd have a MVC framework for stylesheets.

Comment: This is my interview question. That's why i'm asking. If you know or can you clear me, what is that?